# VSTS Database Dacpac release has failure when deploying the package, but the deployment status said succeed

Tags: azure-sql-database, dacpac, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

VSTS Database Dacpac release has failure when deploying the package, but the deployment status said succeed.

Is there a way to fix this so that I can see the deployment fails at the status?Right now if I don't look at the log, I would think the deployment is good.

Below is what I see in the release log, but the deployment status still say succeed:

2016-08-23T21:24:52.2672666Z Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)

2016-08-23T21:24:52.2682666Z Updating database (Start)

2016-08-23T21:24:56.1344991Z An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

2016-08-23T21:24:56.1435001Z Updating database (Failed)

2016-08-23T21:24:56.1575000Z *** Could not deploy package.

2016-08-23T21:24:56.1575000Z Warning SQL72015: The type for column PrincipalInvestigator in table [dbo].[Study] is currently  NVARCHAR (120) NULL but is being changed to  NVARCHAR (60) NULL. Data loss could occur.

2016-08-23T21:24:56.1575000Z Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 50000, Level 16, State 127, Line 6 Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.

2016-08-23T21:24:56.1575000Z Error SQL72045: Script execution error.

Comment: Is this still an issue?  If so, how did you work around it.  I am doing research on DACPAC deployments via VSTS to try uncover risk scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In 'Project Settings', under 'Debug', unselect 'Block incremental deployment if data loss might occur' and save it, it will execute successfully.

But if you are converting from NVARCHAR(120) to NVARCHAR(60) you will end up in data loss.

Comment: I want it to block the deployment so it's behaving right. The problem is, Visual studio team services release job doesn't mark it as a failure, instead it mark it as successful even though the deployment is blocked due to data loss.

Comment: Why visual studio need to mark it as failure? It is potential scenario where I need to change from higher data type to lower data type.

Comment: it's not visual studio the IDE, but the online VSTS, it's a cloud code management and CICD tool. Just like Team Foundation server but on the cloud as a service without having you hosting it.

Comment: You mean VSO, visual studio Online?

Comment: Yes, they are now called Team Services, thus VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services)

Comment: The expected behavior in VSTS is to report the release as failed in this case since the task (deployment of database) was failed as expected.

Comment: And now they call it Azure DevOps.... :D

Answer (score 0):

This must be a bug in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Service). The deployment step has failed correctly as desired but VSTS reported it successful false positively.

Comment: Yup, exactly. That is exactly what happened. I just didn't know if it is a correct behavior or a bug when I asked the question.